# Lightning component not displaying on Salesforce1 menu

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I have been following the Expenses tutorial in the  [Lightning Components developers guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/). All is good, apart from getting the app to display on my Salesforce1 menu.

Followed the instructions on page 42 (Adding Lightning Components to Salesforce1), just not showing up in the menu.

Anybody else have any issues?

Answer (score 5):

The Android version of the Salesforce1 Mobile App does not currently support Lightning Component Tabs. This is a known issue and has a bug filed internally against it. I cannot quote a release date, but it will hopefully be addressed in the near future. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Has anything changed with this now?? Lightning app still does not show up on an Android. Any tips and tricks or workarounds for this?/