# Lightning component not showing on Salesforce1 menu

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-aura-components, android

I created a Lightning component and included it in mobile navigation, but still it's not showing up in salesforce1.

Here is my component code:

```
<aura:component controller="VKSoft_Light.ContactController" implements="force:appHostable">
  <div>Hello</div>
</aura:component>
```

I researched a lot about it , and I ended up with this link  :
[Lightning component not displaying on Salesforce1 menu](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53796/lightning-component-not-displaying-on-salesforce1-menu)

Is it true on this link ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying with Android mobile, I would like to inform you that with Android latest version, it is not working. If possible check with Apple iPhone/iPad, I am sure it will be displayed there.

Regards,
Sudipta