# Lightning tab not display on android salesforce1 app

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-apps, android

Currently android salesforce1 app does not show lightning tabs, I see a response in late 2014 that this feature will be added to salesforce1. By when can we expect this feature?

Comment: seems the android version is still lacking support - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53796/lightning-component-not-displaying-on-salesforce1-menu

Comment: Other than release notes for the next release the community can't really answer when salesforce will deploy functionality. While there's SF staff and developers active here, if you really want an answer to such answers you'd better try official channels. (dev boards, support, your AE, product chatter groups, .. )